# logger is not recognised by local function

Tags: python, logging

I have a python code (below) which issues the error further below and I don't understand where the problem lies. As far as I understand from this [python HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html) the logger should be available to routines called by main() where the logger is defined. I'm using python 2.7.10.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import logging
import sys

def setup():
  logger.debug('some text')
  return 0

def main():
  logger = logging.getLogger('some_logger_name')
  logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
  consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
  consoleHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
  consoleHandler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s: %(message)s'))
  logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

  ret = setup()

if __name__=='__main__':
  sys.exit(main())  # Exit python upon execution of main().
```

Here is the error message I get for running `$python test.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())  # Exit python upon execution of main().
  File "test.py", line 17, in main
    ret = setup()
  File "test.py", line 7, in setup
    logger.debug('some text')
NameError: global name 'logger' is not defined
```

Does any one see my error?

edit:
Thanks for the replies so far! Could you please explain the difference between my version and the one on the python HOWTO I referred to above (I appended the relevant excerpt below).

> If your program consists of multiple modules, here’s an example of how you could organize logging in it:
>
> `# myapp.py`
>      `import logging`
>      `import mylib`
>
> `def main():`
>      `__logging.basicConfig(filename='myapp.log', level=logging.INFO)`
>      `__logging.info('Started')`
>      `__mylib.do_something()`
>      `__logging.info('Finished')`
>
> `if __name__ == '__main__':`
>      `__main()`

Here's the module `mylib.py`:

> `# mylib.py`
>      `import logging`
>
> `def do_something():`
>      `__logging.info('Doing something')`
>
> If you run myapp.py, you should see this in myapp.log:
>
> `INFO:root:Started`
>      `INFO:root:Doing something`
>      `INFO:root:Finished`
>
> which is hopefully what you were expecting to see. You can generalise this to multiple modules, using the pattern in mylib.py.

Arg, sorry for the weird editing. I didn't see how I'm supposed o format quoted code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logger is a local variable set in main() 
You need to declare it in global space.

```
logger=None
def setup():
  logger.debug('some text')
  return 0

def main():
  global logger
  logger = logging.getLogger('some_logger_name')
  logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

  ret = setup()
```

Answer (score 1):

Logging doesn't suspend the usual scoping rules of Python. If you define a local variable inside a function, it's only available inside that function, and that applies to a variable called `logger` just as much as it would to any other function.

If you want all functions in your module to access the same `logger` variable, you need to define it at module level.

Comment: ah, I think I see. If I have the routine `setup` in a separate file (module) it should work. Or, alternatively I can use @lafferc's answer. I didn't know that a local function is treated differently from a module function.